# Python - Loop is only repeating first output

Tags: python, loops

I don't know what's wrong with my code below. The loop is iterating through all the elements in the list but only repeating first output.

I am trying to print even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as space-separated strings on a single line.

Example:
animals = ['elephant', 'monkey', 'tiger']

My code is printing the below

Out[33]:
eehn lpat
eehn lpat
eehn lpat

The output should be:

eehn lpat
mne oky
tgr ie

---

Here is my python 2 code:

```
animals = ['elephant', 'monkey', 'tiger']
w=0
even="" 
odd=""


for animal in animals:
    while (w<len(animal)):
        if (w%2==0):
            even=even+animal[w]
        if (w%2!=0):
            odd=odd+animal[w]
        w=w+1
    print even+' '+odd
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're not resetting `w`, `even` and `odd` after the `while` loops

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you only assign `w` once, at the top.  You should assign it inside the `for` loop each time.  Likewise `even` and `odd`.

Comment: @John-Thank you so much!

Comment: And `elephant` is longer than `monkey` or `tiger` — I mean, the original program would still be flawed, but the outputs would be different if `animals = ['tiger', 'monkey', 'elephant']` because the `while` body would have been executed,

Answer (score 2):

Remember to reset the loop variables after each `animal` in `animals`:

```
>>> w=0
>>> even="" 
>>> odd=""
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for animal in animals:
...     while (w<len(animal)):
...         if (w%2==0):
...             even=even+animal[w]
...         if (w%2!=0):
...             odd=odd+animal[w]
...         w=w+1
...     print even+' '+odd
...     w = 0
...     even = ""
...     odd = ""
... 
eehn lpat
mne oky
tgr ie
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Slicing

When you have a problem in which you have to choose, say even and odd, elements from a sequence Python has something for you, that alleviates the need for an explicit loop and offers a more succinct notation, *the slice notation*.

```
l = [3 ,7, 4, 5, 1, 9]
l[2]        # 4
l[2:3]      # [4]
```

note that with ordinary indices you get an element of the sequence, with the slice notation you get a new list, in our example containing the elements contained between the second and the third *separators*

```
_ 3 _ 7 _ 4 _ 5 _ 1 _ 9 _
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
         ^^^
```

the slice notation uses a number of defaults, e.g., if you don't specify boundaries, 
it goes from the zero-th to the last separator, or in a similar vein

```
l[:]  # a copy of l
l[:3] # [3, 7, 4]
l[3:] # [5, 1, 9]
```

eventually you can specify a step

```
l[0:6:2] # [3, 4, 1]
```

or, simpler

```
l[::2]   # [3, 4, 1]
```

What happens when you start from `1` and use a step 2?

```
l[1::2]  # [7, 5, 9]
```

Given that the slice notation applies also to strings, you can use it to solve all problems of your kind.

<sup><sub>Slice notation has also a shortcut (negative numbers) to count from the end of a sequence, but this is not relevant for your problem so I  won't explain it in detail.</sub></sup>

#### Slicing and your problem

When you use the 
slice notation, that applies also to strings, in Python 2 you have

```
animals = ['elephant', 'monkey', 'tiger']
odd_even = [a[0::2]+' '+a[1::2] for a in animals]
print '\n'.join(odd_even)
```

where you join the different strings together with `'\n'` (that is, the new line character) before printing.

In Python 3 it is either

```
animals = ['elephant', 'monkey', 'tiger']
odd_even = [a[0::2]+' '+a[1::2] for a in animals]
print('\n'.join(odd_even))
```

very similar to Python 2, or

```
animals = ['elephant', 'monkey', 'tiger']
odd_even = [a[0::2]+' '+a[1::2] for a in animals]
print(*odd_even, sep='\n')
```

where you use

- the `sep` *keyword argument* to `print` to have the printed items separated by a newline and
- the `*sequence` syntax, that you can use in a function call to denote that the elements of the sequence must be unfolded and passed as individual arguments to the called function.